# Accessing iOS native code with PhoneGap, build issue

Tags: ios, cordova, native

I've wrote a very simple plugin and added it to my config.xml:

```
<feature name="FileWriter">
    <param name="ios-package" value="FileWriter" />
</feature>
```

after executing "Cordova prepare" it does not copy it to the staging/config.xml, and thus when I run the app I get an error:

```
2014-11-18 14:12:58.929 iOS Test[1280:723270] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "FileWriter1220649673",
  "FileWriter",
  "cordovaGetFileContents",
  [

  ]
]
```

If I manually add the feature to the config.xml found in the platform folder it works fine.

Basically there seems to be some sort of step missing in the "cordova prepare" step which is not copying this feature.  All of the other elements in the base config.xml are copied properly to the platform specific one.

I've based the code off of the [tutorial here](http://moduscreate.com/building-a-custom-phonegap-plugin-for-ios/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the oficial tutorial instead
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

The one you linked is missing the part of the `plugin.xml`, that's the file read on `cordova prepare` to copy the necessary files to the iOS project.